# powerautomate - check empty field condition

Tags: power-automate

I am doing approval flow with powerautomate.
some of my approval processes don't need 1st level (manager) approval.
so I want to do it by not filling in the manager name when I add new item.

-if the manager name is empty field found in Sharepoint list, >  update the item with "manager null" in approval history column.

the following screenshot is my flow. but it didn't not update the item if the manager column is empty.
only working if the manager file has value, and it update the item.

how can I achieve the empty field check.?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume your Manager field allows multiple values and is of type person or group. This is because I see you have an apply to each loop.

I would remove the apply to each and simply check the length of the Manager field itself, not one of its properties like displayName,etc (that will add the loop).

Below is an example.

1. In the condition I used this expression. Add that via the expression editor:

   length(triggerOutputs()?['body/Manager'])

[image]